# How to use ASP.Net MVC4 Web API with AngularJS partial views (aka ng-include)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

Is it possible to return **'*.htm'** files from the ASP.Net MVC4 Web API application?

I am trying to use AngularJs to manage the client side views and when I include the following commend on my page:

```
<div ng-controller="application.RootController">
    <div ng-switch="subview" >
        <div ng-switch-when="home" ng-include="'../Views/Angular/customer/overview.htm'"></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="admin" ng-include="'../Views/Angular/Admin/home.htm'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see that this is working as expected on the browser, but the ASP.Net is returning 404 page not found.

Also I am unable to physically browse any of the htm pages, so is there a special thing i need to do in ASP.Net MVC in terms of configuring the routing to return out the htm pages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Files in the `~/Views` folder are not served directly. You should place your HTM pages somewhere else. For example you could have an `~/Angular` folder.

Comment: wow! couldn't think about this one. Also had to include the "routes.IgnoreRoute("*.htm*");" and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your should place static files into '/static' folder

Answer (score 0):

You can call `razor` `@html.partial` to display your partial views

```
<div ng-controller="application.RootController">
    <div ng-switch="subview" >
        <div ng-switch-when="admin"> @Html.partial("~/Views/Angular/Admin/home.htm")</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not a good idea with angular especially if there are directives on that partial page. If you're using the 'controller as' syntax, its a pain in the ass to bind the directives to the controller.